# 403 When trying to add a list item with REST API

Tags: rest, spfx

I've been trying to get this function to post an item to a Sharepoint list, however it's been coming back as a 403 each time. The `formDigest` value populates each time I console log it and I can see it in the network request headers, however not sure what else would be causing the issue. I'm hoping it's something really simple I'm just not seeing. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
public submitReport() {

let formDigest = "";
let reportedby: string = this.state.userEmail;
let page: string = this.state.location;
let note: string = this.state.feedback;
axios.post('https://<SITE URL>/_api/contextinfo')
.then((res) => {
  formDigest = res.data.FormDigestValue;
  console.log('formdigest: ' + formDigest);
})
.then(() => {
  axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "https://<SITE URL>/sites/intranet/help/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<LIST TITLE>')/items",
    headers: {
      "X-RequestDigest": formDigest,
      "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    data: {
      '__metadata': {
        'type': 'SP.Data.User_x0020_FeedbackListItem'
      },
      'Title': new Date(),
      'ReportedBy': reportedby,
      'Page': page,
      'Note': note
    }
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
})
```

}

Comment: Do you have add item permission on List?

Comment: how about using `"X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,` ?

Comment: Why are you not using the the spfx-way with:

import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';

Comment: Are you fetching the formdigest from the same site you are trying to post to: site/intranet/help/_api/contextinfo ?

Comment: @AndersAune Yes that was definitely the problem. I've never worked with the `x-formdigest` header before and I thought the one from the root of the domain was all I needed. I knew it was something obvious like this thank you! Totally working now.

Comment: Don't forget that this x-formdigest expires after a half hour...

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the spfx-functionality with

```
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse, ISPHttpClientOptions } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
```

You don't need any digit - the framework does this for you (you also don't have the problem of an expired x-requestdigit).
You could do it in the following way:

```
var itemType = "SP.Data.User_x0020_FeedbackListItem";
var absoluteUri = this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl;

const itemData: any = {
    "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
    'Title': new Date(),
    'ReportedBy': reportedby,
    'Page': page,
    'Note': note
};
const itemHeader: any = {
    'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
    'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
    'odata-version': '',
    "X-HTTP-Method": "POST"
};
const spHttpClientOptions: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
    "headers": itemHeader,
    "body": JSON.stringify(itemData)
};

this.props.context.spHttpClient.post(
    absoluteUri + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<LIST TITLE>')/items",
    SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
    spHttpClientOptions);
```